# django model - queryset issue

Tags: python, database, django

I am trying to search for an item in db. there are two items in db, but i cannot get the second one somehow. with my code below the result is only the first row of `Bewertung` but not the second one.

my code is simple:

```
locations = Location.objects.all()[:5] 
bewertungs = Bewertung.objects.filter(von_location__in=locations)
```

what can be the reason of why i cannot find the second entry in db? i am getting the first record where `bewertung` is 4, but the second isnot coming up in the result.

**EDIT**:

this is the Bewertung Model.

```
class Bewertung(models.Model):
   von_location= models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_bewertung",default="")
   von_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="users_bewertung",default="")
   price_leistung = models.IntegerField(max_length=5,default=00)
   romantic = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,default=00)
   bewertung = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,default=00)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.bewertung
```

these are the records:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your entire model here?

Comment: what about `bewertung = Bewertung.objects.filter(bewertung__contains=int(int_bew))`

Comment: You should really write your code in English. It helps a lot when getting help on forums like this for one thing (plus python is already in English!) And "int_bew" is not a very descriptive name, a better name would be "bew_pk" (pk == primary key, this is standard python notation)

Comment: Have you actually checked the database to ensure the record exists?

Comment: ``locations = Location.objects.all()[:5]
   bewertungs = Bewertung.objects.filter(von_location__in=locations)``

this is what i am doing basically to get ALL bewertungs. but i am failing. @catherine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Bewertung(models.Model):
   //you don't have to put default="" because this is already required
   von_location= models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_bewertung")
   von_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="users_bewertung")

   //use DecimalField instead of IntergerField
   //use max_digits not max_length because it is for string
   price_leistung = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_place=2, default=0)
   romantic = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_place=2, default=0)
   bewertung = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_place=2, default=0)

   //you return your unicode with an int field which result to error 
   //so you must do it this way
   def __unicode__(self):
       return "{0}".format(self.bewertung)
```

Comment: I try your codes for filtering and it works on me. Maybe you missed something in your codes.